# Temporary return for function

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to get my data from localStorage, because it is faster and avaible offline, and then get data from web, let's say ajax call.

```
function getdata(){
    function loadViaAjax(){
        localStorage.data=newerData;
        return newerData;
    }
    if(localStorage.data){
        return localStorage.data;
    }
}
toBeInseretIntoDOM=getData();    //AngularJS will do this part
```

The goal is to get the `localStorage.data` first, since the user can have slow connection and old informations is still better than none, and simultaneously do the `ajax request` to get then newest data.
Logicically, the localStorage's data will be faster so they should be returned to be procesed and inserted into DOM, but once the ajax catch up, the data should get updated.

Comment: What's the use case for this? I mean, if you need to get the data from the server then the info you're displaying from localStorage is either not complete or inaccurate. If it is incomplete then it only would make sense to fetch it if the user asks to. If it is inaccurate then it doesn't make sense to get it from localStorage. In any case, if you want to delay the server request you can always use javascript's `setTimeout`

Comment: Imagine it is on your phone and the phone have on internet connection, I want to get at least the last session data and if the user get his internet connection back, he should get the newest informations.

Comment: Well there's a big difference between that and getting it from the server a few seconds later as you mentioned in your post. If that is the case then you should be asking how to check for internet connection on a mobile device if anything. Actually I don' think I even know what the question is to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function that sometimes acts asynchronously and sometimes doesn't (or, in your case, always both), then I've found that the best thing to do is to treat it like it's always asynchronous. In other words, pass it a callback and always act on the results from there:

```
function getdata(callback) {
    $.get(data_url, function(response) {
        callback(response);
    });
    callback(localStorage.data);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
getdata(function(data) {
    // do something
});
```

Note that the callback doesn't have to care whether the data was retrieved synchronously or not. It can just act on the data it receives.

A similar pattern is to return the data if you have it and go get it if you don't:

```
function getdata(callback) {
    if (localStorage.data) {
        callback(localStorage.data);
    } else {
        $.get(data_url, function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Way better. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thats going to only fetch the data from the server if localStorage.data is not set, which is not what you requested. P.S kinda mean to change the accepted answer :(

Comment: @Mike - That's only true of my second example, which I included merely for comparison

Answer (score 2):

```
function setdata(data){
 //do whatever you need to with your data here
 }

function getdata(){
   $.get(data_url,function(response){
         setdata(response);
    });

   if(localStorage.data){ 
        setdata(localStorage.data);
   }

}
```

When `getdata` is called an ajax request will be immediately sent out. Without waiting for a reply the data is set from local storage (if it exists) with `setdata`. When the ajax request receives a response `setdata` is called again, but this time with the server data.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you are saying ...

*I want to keep the last copy of the data available in localStorage, but once in a while I want to see if I can freshen that data by `Ajax`.*

If that is the case, then you could so something like..

```
// This is not complete code ...
function loadData(callback) {
  getFromCache() {
    var data = window.localStorage.getItem("mystuff");
    if (data) {
      callback(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }


  handleSuccess(data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("mystuff", JSON.stringify(data));
    callback(data);
  }

  var ajaxConfig = {
    url: "http://example.com",
    error: getFromCache,
    success: handleSuccess
  }
  // Trigger ajax call here...
  // You can even use a window.setTimeout() here
  // to see if the ajax event takes too long -- if so
  // cancel it and call getFromCache
}
```